# How to fix spawn ENAMETOOLONG error nrwl nx workspace

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I generated a week ago an angular project with nrwl/nx at that time I could generate libs and components and could start my project but right now I am getting the following error:

```
spawn ENAMETOOLONG
```

This error occurs whenever I am trying to run npm run start which runs nx serve right now. ng serve is not working either. I can run npm install but nothing to start my application. Here is my package.json if you need any other information I can provide it:

```
{
  "name": "moniesta-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "@nebular/auth": "^9.0.1",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^9.0.1",
    "@nebular/theme": "^9.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "13.8.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/jest": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/linter": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/tao": "13.8.1",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.8.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.10.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "~8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "27.2.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

This happens when i am using nx reset and after that using nx serve again:

```
   Log file with the error: C:\Users\Hasan\OneDrive\Desktop\Moniesta-Projects\Moniesta-Combinatioon\moniesta-management\moniesta-admin\node_modules\.cache\nx\d\daemon-error.log
   Please file an issue at https://github.com/nrwl/nx
   Nx Daemon is going to be disabled until you run "nx reset".
```

In the Daemon log it just says the same error:

```
 NX   spawn ENAMETOOLONG
```

Comment: can no one help me out`? Or do you need more information if yes I can provide any information you need

Comment: I have encountered the same issue. Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 45):

This error usually appears when you have too many uncommited files (in a range more than 700 or so in my experience). Commiting the files will usually solve the problem.

Comment: It was a shocker was git status showed.

Comment: ran `git status` to check this... and wow did I have a lot of files listed. I ran `git stash` and was able to build afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same issue. I did delete the **node_modules** folder manually, then re-installed everything with npm install. Also found that there is a new **.angular** folder in root folder, which was not present earlier. After deleting this folder entirely, I was able to run build again. Not really sure if running **nx build** once (which populates this folder again) you should not wipe it out once more.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer I will try this out today later after work

Comment: Deleting the .angular folder solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue. The solution that worked for me, I found it [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9037#issuecomment-1047975322)

In my case, I was getting this error when running `npm start`, `nx serve`. After deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install`, I found that running `npm install` was giving me this error too.

I had uncommitted changes on the branch. The error disappeared after committing the work.

Comment: I had a lot of uncommited changes after commiting, problem went away

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it's related to GIT but yes, having too many uncommitted files is the main cause of the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32473158)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solve it like this:

**First:** Updating Nx to version **13.8.5**. Do as below:

1. Run command: *nx migrate @nrwl/workspace@13.8.5*
2. Run command: *npm install*
3. Run command: *nx migrate --run-migrations*
4. Remove "migrations.json" file in nx workspace root directory

**Second:** Re-install npm globally based on nx version 13.8.5. Do as below:

1. Run command: *npm i -g nx@13.8.5*

Comment: I had the same error with `nx@14.8.4`, upgrading to `nx@14.8.6` resolved the issue for me. @kamran-taghaddos, would you mind updating your answer to mention the `14.x` range version update as well please? @natyus, if you haven't figured this out yet, try this solution. (not sure why my `@user` mentions aren't working here, sorry..)

Comment: BUT that doesn't actually seem to have fixed the error... at first I thought it had, but I'm still getting the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was as @jurev described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72256247/15635400), but the root cause of the problem was not so obvious.

I defined a local directory for a project and initialized local repo, then downloaded the project from remote repo into the directory and connected local repo with remote repo. As a result, I had nothing to commit but `git status`
showed that all of the files are not staged for further commit and `nx serve..` returned `spawn ENAMETOOLONG`.

For me the solution was deletion the whole project directory, downloading some client for version control system (for example, TortoiseGit) and clone the project from remote repo using the client and providing a link of the remote repo to it. After that `nx serve` worked perfectly.